# Как использовать SMTP в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, smtp, email

В Битрикс можно настроить SMTP (Настройки -> Настройки продукта -> Почтовые и СМС события -> Настройки SMTP). Я создал SMTP, а как его использовать на сайте? Поиск по гуглу и яндексу ничего не дал (разве что использование в Битрикс24, но мы не используем его).

Comment: так smpt или smtp?

Comment: smtp, была опечатка в названии

Answer (score 0):

[В документации по настройке локального SMTP](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=23612) указано:

> Отправка писем от имени и адреса, указанного при настройке локального
> SMTP-сервера, возможна только в тех случаях, когда в письме можно
> выбрать отправителя. Например, при создании Рассылок в Маркетинг >
> E-mail-маркетинг > Рассылки , отправке писем из CRM или из раздела
> Почта корпоративного портала.

Т.е. вы можете с этого ящика отправлять только рассылки из административной части битрикс, а для настройки отправки всех писем нужно настраивать сервер (если виртуальная машина [то вот инструкция](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&CHAPTER_ID=08853))

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы в продуктах 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом и коробочных версиях Битрикс24 включить возможность использования SMTP-сервера отправителя, отредактируйте файл /bitrix/.settings.php , добавив секцию smtp со следующим кодом:

'smtp' =>
array (
'value' =>
array(
'enabled' => true,
'debug' => true, //optional
'log_file' => '/var/mailer.log', //optional
),
),

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=23612